# get list all groups facebook graph api v2.5 or how to use the v2.3?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

well this is my get

```
    public GraphResponse Get(String query,Bundle parameters)
    {
        final GraphResponse[] respuesta = new GraphResponse[1];
        /* make the API call */

        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                query,
                parameters,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */

                        respuesta[0] =response;
                    }
                }
        ).executeAndWait();
return  respuesta[0];
    }
```

and this works fines with `me` queries now I tried with `me/groups` query, now if I try get all the group where user is memeber of, I got

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

this happens too on explorer in

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
```

on this last I had choosen all the permission and especial permission
and I got the same answer.

[image]

then my ask is, If there is not a way for get this list on V2.5 how can I (continue using the version 2.5) "change" for (only) this query the version to 2.3 where it does works?

I tried doing this query   `/v2.3/me/groups`
but I got blank answer.

> My app facebook was created "today"

Comment: You have to use v2.5 and you can only get groups you are admin of

Comment: as wizkid said, you cannot downgrade. but why build something with a feature that will be removed sooner or later because it is deprecated?

Comment: is it possible using FQL? I want to create a multi post group app

Comment: HAHAHAHA. Guess why we removed the possibility to get all group? SO YOU CAN'T SPAM!

Comment: what you want to create is illegal. and FQL is deprecated.

Comment: it wouldn't be spam, this would be a helper for example if you are member of ten groups and you want to public a photo normaly, you need public it on every group, with "an" app where you can select what groups you wish public and then press "public" and automatically public in the ten groups (one time, no spam it).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get ALL groups anymore, it is only possible to get groups you manage with the `user_managed_groups` permission and the `/me/groups` endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly what you want, but if you know the group id you can query all the members by using an access token and this url to get you started
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{enter group id}/members?access_token={enter your access token}&limit=1000